# How to Auto generate the script for database creation in Visual Studio based on which I will create database in SSMS

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, ssms

Visual Studio auto generates the database and all the tables based on your projects models and so when running the project for the first time. I was wondering if it is possible to export the SQL commands  that create the database in Visual Studio into a script, so I could then execute those SQL query commands in the SSMS and create database there via script.

Comment: Do you mean Sql Project ? If yes, Yes you can get the script using dacpac

Comment: Actually no, I mean a regular ASP.net Web App (MVC), Asp.Net Core 3.1 to be specific.